# Python requests.get request returning 400 on URL that works in browser

Tags: python, url, python-requests

I am attempting to web scrape based on a training course for Python I am taking. I have installed BeautifulSoup and that seems to run fine. The website is https://pixelford.com/blog/ and when I remove "/blog/" from the URL, the code runs fine. But when I add "/blog/", I receive a 400 error, even though I know that the URL works, as I can navigate to the website:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://pixelford.com/blog/"
response = requests.get(url)
print(response)
html = response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
a_tags = soup.find_all('a', class_="entry_title_link")

for a_tag in a_tags:
    print(a_tag.get_text())

titles = list(map(lambda a_tag: a_tag.get_text(), a_tags))

print(titles)
```

I was trying to scrape a list of the blog titles from the URL and put them in a list but instead python just returns an empty list.

Comment: `400` Bad Request response status code indicates that the server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (for example, malformed request syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### 400 Error Response

When you make a `requests.get` request without passing any parameters besides the URL, it includes some additional basic information, for example (taken from Fiddler):

```
GET http://pixelford.com/blog/ HTTP/1.1
Host: pixelford.com
User-Agent: python-requests/2.28.0
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
Connection: keep-alive
```

In particular, note the User-Agent (UA) string, which makes it clear that a python script made the requests using `requests`.

It is likely that the server is configured to block requests with a similar UA string. We can check this further by using a custom UA in a web browser, for example in FireFox you can navigate to `about:config` and specify one:

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| general.useragent.override | python-requests/2.28.0 |

This results in:

[image: Screenshot of FireFox navigated to https://pixelford.com/blog and returning a 400 - Bad Request error]

You can get around this by specifying your own UA string in your code:

```
>>> requests.get("https://pixelford.com/blog/")
<Response [400]>
>>> requests.get("https://pixelford.com/blog/", headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
<Response [200]>
```

In the last request here with the custom UA, we can see that the request was successful. For reference, the raw request now contained:

```
GET http://pixelford.com/blog/ HTTP/1.1
Host: pixelford.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
Connection: keep-alive
```

It's worth noting that it is fairly common for sites to rely on UA strings, for example to try to gauge what features the requester may have available and so what content to serve, Stack Overflow does this, and indeed it's very possible to send requests with UA strings that Stack Overflow simply won't except, for example, a blank UA:

[image: Screenshot showing a Stack Exchange "Access Denied" page, the User-Agent is listed as an empty string]

---

##### Selector Bug

When you have fixed your request, then you just need to fix the typo in your `class_` selector, it should be `"entry-title-link"`, not `"entry_title_link"`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://pixelford.com/blog/"
response = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
print(response)
html = response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
a_tags = soup.find_all('a', class_="entry-title-link")

for a_tag in a_tags:
    print(a_tag.get_text())

titles = list(map(lambda a_tag: a_tag.get_text(), a_tags))

print(titles)
```

> ```
> <Response [200]>
> Get Rid of Photo Bombers
> The External Light Meter: Your New Best Friend
> Bridal Gown: Capturing the Details of the Dress
> Shooting a Wedding
> The Growth of Baby Jill
> Jake Neopolt, “Fire in the Sky” album cover
> Chen Family
> Juliane and Hanz
> The Authentic Charm of Coney Island
> Brooklyn Bridge – One Bridge, So Many Options
> ['Get Rid of Photo Bombers', 'The External Light Meter: Your New Best Friend', 'Bridal Gown: Capturing the Details of the Dress', 'Shooting a Wedding', 'The Growth of Baby Jill', 'Jake Neopolt, “Fire in the Sky” album cover', 'Chen Family', 'Juliane and Hanz', 'The Authentic Charm of Coney Island', 'Brooklyn Bridge – One Bridge, So Many Options']
> ```

Comment: Thank you for the response! I do get back the 200 response now but am still not receiving back the blog titles in a list. The training video I am watching seems to be running with no errors but I just get "[]" returned.

Comment: @DavidandBethany You have a typo in your selector, the class is `entry-title-link`, not `entry_title_link`